# Get string (part of text) of the website address

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get and write a custom word that appears as a result of a search query.

The word for example in this case is "test" (the word test was searched):
http://www.mialias.net/?s=test&lang=es

I'm trying to put that on a text on the WordPress page like this:

```
<h2>Search results for:</h2><h3>test</h3>
```

Any idea how to get it and write it with PHP?

Comment: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']); ?>` ???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use [request](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

```
<h2>Search results for:</h2><h3>test <?php echo $_REQUEST['s']; ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are technically correct. Of the two, $_GET is the best way to do this.

**PLEASE DON'T DO THIS.**

Using unfiltered $_GET['s'] in your output creates a vulnerability in your page that almost any developer can exploit. All they need to do is pass in a correctly crafted payload on the URL and your page can be made to execute arbitrary code. Use the `filter_var()` function to sanitize the string before displaying it.

`filter_var()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

**Types of Filters**

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

**Sanitize Filters**

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$filterd_s = filter_var($_GET['s'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>
. . . Skipping stuff here . . . 
<h2>Search results for:</h2><h3>test <?php echo $filtered_s; ?></h3>
```

That will safely display the variable. If your user passes in something bad, you might see something odd, but it won't cause harm.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: I like to use `filter_input` because it gets the values before directives like magic quotes have changed the value: `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 's', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`

Comment: Sonny. No clue. I thought it was valid advice. :S